# connecting forms with each other using a module

Tags: vb.net, forms, module, show-hide, toolstripbutton

I'm new to programming and have a problem in VB.net

For a project with a couple of forms, I wanted to work with a module that automatic loads a menu (toolstrip) in a form (kind of CSS in web develop). This works for the first time but if I repeat the action the menu disappears. (eg drivers > Taxi > drivers).

I think the error is when I (re)load the form.

Here is my code

**Module code**

Declaration:

```
Public tsbdrivers, tsbTaxi As New ToolStripButton
Public tsMenu As New ToolStrip
```

Properties of tsMenu

```
With tsMenu
        .Dock = DockStyle.Left
        .Text = "Navigatie, klik op knoppen om iets raad te plegen"
        'toolstrip bevolkeren
        .Items.Add(tsbchauffeurs)
        .Items.Add(tsbTaxi)
    End With
    'probs drivers
    With tsbdrivers
        .DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image
        .Image = Taxi2014.My.Resources.Resources.Chauffeurs
        .ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.None
        .Text = "Raadpleeg uw chauffeurs en/of werknemers."
        AddHandler .Click, AddressOf DriverOpen
    End With
    'probs Taxi
    With tsbTaxi
        .DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image
        .Image = Taxi2014.My.Resources.Resources.Wagens
        .ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.None
        .Text = "Raadpleeg uw wagens."
        AddHandler .Click, AddressOf TaxiOpen
    End With
End Sub
```

(Image are imported images)

Public subs

```
Public Sub DriverOpen()
    HideAll()
    Frmdriver.Show()
End Sub

Public Sub TaxiOpen()
    HideAll()
    Frmdriver.Show()
End Sub

 Public Sub HideAll()
    FrmMenu.Hide()
    FrmDrivers.Hide()
    frmTaxi.Hide()
End Sub
```

**Code in the 2 forms**

```
Private Sub frmTaxi_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Menu toevoegen

    Afbeeldingeninladentoolstrips()
    Me.Controls.Add(tsMenu)
End sub
```

I don't know if it matters, but for most of my forms I use datasets.
Can anyone please help me? I will thank you a thousand times. :D